How can I have syntax (e.g. Statement) inside PreProc inherit PreProc's background?
Vim 9.0, macos, no vimrc, totally stock
I run these commands:
set termguicolors
highlight clear
highlight Statement ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE
highlight PreProc ctermbg=red guibg=red

and I see this result:

What I expected was for the NONE to mean "use the background of what you are contained within" or something like that, but apparently not. How can I fix this?
My desired result would be a red background for if, return and nullptr inside the macro, but not outside.

Syntax items can not inherit attributes from parent group, unless intentionally defined as :h :syn-transparent.
So, no, you can't.

So if I define a background for PreProc, is there no way to have that background not get stomped by any other syntax found inside, even if there’s no background highlight defined for that other syntax? I may be using the terms a bit wrong, but hopefully you get the intent.

@John_C Syntax is one thing, and highlight is another thing. I don't fully understand what you're trying to achieve but it could be some kind of misuse.

@John_C I see now. You have two cStatement things defined by syntax rules. Then you want to make Vim treat them differently. That is, change syntax rule using highlight commands. No, it doesn't work like this. It's clearly a misuse. If syntax says "it's the same thing" then highlight obeys. If you don't like this then change syntax.

Tbh I'm getting a bit confused. I just want my C macro definitions have a nice background without gaps in, I don't mind how.

@John_C One does not simply walk into Mordor. 9 out of 10 newbies simply want "to change colors a bit" while in fact trying to rewrite syntax in some way. Better forget it.
